# Some Functions Not working in newer Compilers

Tags: c, visual-studio, sleep, turbo-c++

I was using TurboC++ and i have changed to Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop and i even tried Dev C++.
I am getting error in both the newer compilers but not in turbo C++

```
struct date d;
sleep(3);
```

I Want to know alternatives for these functions

Further to change background and foreground color, i was told to use

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_RED);
```

These work perfectly fine but the fact is that it has only a limited number of colors (3 each, i suppose)
Like, i cant change textcolor to white! HOW TO DO IT??

Comment: First of all, if you have a question about build errors, then please include them in the question *unedited* and *complete*. Secondly, don't place two unrelated questions in a single question.

Comment: For `sleep`, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70d6b00b-9708-4d94-893f-0f3ae7b3ef20/sleepint

Answer (score 0):

You can define New color and use it as existed ones

```
#define FOREGROUND_WHITE (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN)
```

The below code will print different combinations of foreground and background color
based on result, pass values as you want.

```
for(i=0; i<255; i++)
{
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), i);
printf("NEW COLOUR=%d\n",i);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
/*
//0-black
//1-blue
//2-green
//  ......
//15-white



//0-15-black back ground, text colour as above 0-black,15-white
//16-31blue back ground,  text colour as above 16+0 -black 16+15-white
//32-47green back ground, text colour as above 32+0 -black 32+15-white
// ......
//240-white back ground,  text colour as above 240+0 -black 240+15-white
*/


int main()
{
int i;

    for(i=0; i<256; i++) //loop to print text colours 0-15 total 16 colours
    {
        // Sleep( 3000 );   // sleep three seconds
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), i);
        printf("Text colour=%d\n",i);
    }
    system("pause");


    for(i=0; i<256; i=i+8) //background colours 0-15 total 16 back grounds
    {
        //    Sleep( 3000 );   // sleep three seconds
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), i);
        printf("Back ground=%d\n",i);
    }
    system("pause");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0+15);  //white text +black background

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Sir i dont want randoms but SO I just Defined FOREGROUND WHITE the way u said and then used it as others and it worked! PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO USE OTHERS BY DEFINING; Like BLACK BACKGROUND or any color any where!!?????

Comment: OK Added an example with that you can.